# PHP array unique on multi dimensional array/object

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying for a while. I have tried several things to fix this, but I just can't get it to work.

My code:

```
<?php
if (is_array($row))
{
    foreach ($row as $data) {

        echo array_unique($data->username);
    } 
}
?>
```

It gives me the following error

> Message: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

I have no idea what is going on with this. I have even tried placing the `array_unique` in the `$row`.

So like:

```
<?php
if (is_array($row))
{
    foreach (array_unique($row) as $data) {

        echo $data->username;
    } 
}
?>
```

But this gives me another error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I have no idea what's going on. I have searched for hours but haven't found anything on here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: output of: `print_r($row);` is ... ? expected output is ... ?

Comment: `array_unique` works on flat arrays, even if you cast `(array) $row` as array it still won't work, just create a temporary container to check

Comment: Hey @Ghost You have like answered 75% of all my questions! :) Thanks for that :) What exactly do you mean? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `array_unique` on multi-dimensional arrays when you're looking inside the depth. Its works on flat one, and certainly won't work on strings. An alternative is to create another container for that and use usernames as keys, then you'll get unique ones.

Since you haven't shown the array/object structure, here a little bit on an idea on the comment I gave above:

```
$container = array();
foreach($row as $data) {
    if(!isset($container[$data->username])) {
        $container[$data->username] = $data;
    }
}
// $container = array_values($container); // optional simple reindex
```

Comment: @TaylorSwift sure glad i was able to help again